# M2MQTT throwing communicationException on mqttclint.connet

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, mqtt, self-signed

Below is my code snippet to coonect to MQTT with SSL certificates

```cs
X509Certificate caCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Path.Combine("D:\Certificates", "cacert.pem"));
X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine("D:\Certificates", "molexClient.pfx"), "molex");
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(address, MQTTPort, secure: false, caCert, clientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);
client.ProtocolVersion = MqttProtocolVersion.Version_3_1;
client.Connect(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),UserName, Password);
```

on line `client.connect()`, I am getting below exception.

```
uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException: 'Exception of type 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttCommunicationException' was thrown.'
```

[image: screenhot of M2MQTTCommunicationException]

I have disabled firewalls and validate certificates as well. Still getting same exception. Also tried connect method only with clientId without username and password still getting same issue. Tried different browser.

Comment: The MQTTCommunicationException should have an inner exception or caused by field that should show some hint as to the underlying problem. At is is there is not enough information here to help.

Comment: It is not shaowing any other exception.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Tried different browser." This code shouldn't be running in any browser